# conditional in lambda not returning desired results

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to organize many phone numbers based on their digit lengths using lambda how ever my conditional statement seems to be reading the df incorrectly. at the moment it is returning everything as false what I would like it to do is look in the column "length" grab the number and check if that number is equal to 10 and apply the formatting. the string formatting works with out the conditional state, but i have string lengths ranging from 0 - 15 characters which all require separate formatting so I would like it to check the column length for the number and apply formatting appropriately. right now I'm just trying to get 10 digit numbers to work.

```
Phone['Phone Number'] = Phone['Phone Number'].str.replace(' ', '')

#Sorts Phone Number by length
Phone.index = Phone['Phone Number'].str.len()
PhoneLength = Phone.sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

#Creates Table with Phone Numbers Number of Digits in Phone PhoneLength
Phone['Length'] = Phone['Phone Number'].str.len()
PhoneLength.sort_values('Length', ascending=False, inplace=True)

PhoneLength['Correct']=PhoneLength['Phone Number'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ('('+x[:3]+')'+x[3:6]+'-'+x[6:10]) if ['Length'] == (10)  else print ('False'))
```

What I want it to do

```
    Phone Number    Length  Correct
0   1151464301      10        Correctly Formatted Number Here
2   1919772014      10        Correctly Formatted Number Here
3   1919472011      10        Correctly Formatted Number Here
4   2484731500      10        Correctly Formatted Number Here
```

Comment: Can you add some input data so we can replicate the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Phone.apply(lambda x: ('('+str(x['Phone Number'])[:3]+')'+str(x['Phone Number'])[3:6]+'-'+str(x['Phone Number'])[6:10]) if x['Length'] == 10 else 'False', axis = 1)
```

The problem with your approach above is your apply function is only on the PhoneLength['Phone Number'] column. The 'Length' column is not available. You could recompute the length column with an approach similar to your initial attempt:

```
Phone['Phone Number'].astype('str').apply(lambda x: ('('+x[:3]+')'+x[3:6]+'-'+x[6:10]) if len(x) == 10  else 'False')
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this would be like the following example:

```
# Create a DataFrame
Phone = pd.DataFrame({'Phone Number':['312 422 3344', '432 345 33444']})

# Remove space character
Phone['Phone Number'] = Phone['Phone Number'].str.replace(' ', '')

# Create a new column "Length" and sort "Phone Number" by "Length"
Phone['Length'] = Phone['Phone Number'].str.len()
Phone.sort_values(by = 'Length', ascending = False, inplace = True)

# Create a new column: Correct 
Phone['Correct'] = Phone[Phone['Length']==10]['Phone Number'].apply(lambda x: ('('+x[:3]+')'+x[3:6]+'-'+x[6:10]))
```

You can put the last line of code into a `for` loop for different lengths and you're done. A neat way to do it would be defining a function though.